# Where are used priority queues in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, sorting

I have this implementation of maximum priority queue:

```
"use strict";

// insert - N
// remove maximum - 1
class MaxPQ {
  constructor(queue) {
    this._pq = [];
    this._size = 0;

    if (!queue) {
      this._size = 0;
    } else {
      this._size = queue.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < this._size; i++) {
        this._pq[i + 1] = queue[i];
      }

      for (let k = Math.floor(this._size / 2); k >= 1; k--) {
        this._sink(k);
      }
    }
  }

  isEmpty() {
    return this._size === 0;
  }

  get size() {
    return this._size;
  }

  get max() {
    return this._pq[1];
  }

  insert(item) {
    this._pq[++this._size] = item;
    this._swim(this._size);
  }

  deleteMax() {
    let max = this._pq[1];
    this._exch(1, this._size--);
    this._sink(1);
    this._pq[this._size + 1] = null;
    return max;
  }

  _swim(k) {
    while (k > 1 && this._less(Math.floor(k / 2), k)) {
      this._exch(k, Math.floor(k / 2));
      k = Math.floor(k / 2);
    }
  }

  _sink(k) {
    while (2 * k <= this._size) {
      let j = 2 * k;
      if (j < this._size && this._less(j, j + 1)) {
        j++;
      }
      if (!this._less(k, j)) {
        break;
      }
      this._exch(k, j);
      k = j;
    }
  }

  _less(i, j) {
    return this._pq[i] < this._pq[j];
  }

  _exch(i, j) {
    let temp = this._pq[i];
    this._pq[i] = this._pq[j];
    this._pq[j] = temp;
  }
}

module.exports = MaxPQ;
```

It is work fine. It get/remove the maximum number from array without sorting.

But I don`t understand where it can be useful. Can you tell me the possible examples for use in javascript and Node.js

Suppose, I have array of priority of something. From 1 to 10. But how I link this to item, how I recognize for which item this priority. In java author use some Key generic type.

I take this algorithm from book Algorithms, Sedgewick [link to source](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/)

Comment: Did you even think about Googling this?  The wikipedia article contains seven sample applications of a priority queue.

Comment: Queues are like lines whose order is based on some criteria. It may be arrival time FIFO, or something more interesting like thread priority. You use it where you need that behavior. They can also be used as the base of other data structures.